# How to query and display subcollections with Angular?

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am working on my first angular/firestore app and have gotten to the point where I can display document data from a single collection with no subcollections. I am trying to expand on this and display data from a subcollection. My firestore database looks like this.

Users -> userIDs - > Fights - > fightIds

I am now trying to display the fights on my page, so I am trying to  query the subcolection of Fights and code that into my component.

my TS:

```js
    @Component({
     selector: 'app-my-fights',
    templateUrl: './my-fights.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./my-fights.component.css']
    })
    export class MyFightsComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {

    
    userId: any;
    fights$: Observable<any>;
    users$: Observable<any>;
    user: any;
    private readonly subscription: Subscription;
    fightCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<any>;

   

    
     constructor(private afs: AngularFirestore, private firestoreData: FirestoreDataService, public auth: 
    AuthService, private fightTest: FightService) {
    this.subscription = auth.user$.subscribe(user => {
    this.userId = user.uid
    this.fightCollection = this.afs.collection<any>(`users/${this.userId}/Fights`);
    this.fights$ = this.fightCollection.valueChanges();
    
  
       });
      }

      ngOnInit() {
   
       }

      ngOnDestroy() {
       this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  
    
     }

    }
```

user ID is pulled from the injected authentication service I created. I put userID into a variable just to test if I can pull uid correctly. I then try to code the userId value into the correct firestore path to pull that users Fights collection and assign it to an observable.

My HTML:

```html
      <ul *ngFor="let fight of fights | async">
     <li>
      fight.blueFighter;
     </li>
    </ul>
```

for simplicity sake I am just trying to pull the field blueFIghter for now.

I am not getting any errors but nothing is being displayed either. I can't tell if I am even reading the collection properly, or just not calling it in HTML correctly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Return a sub-collection in firebase using Angular firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58546545/return-a-sub-collection-in-firebase-using-angular-firestore)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the way you build your observables. Don't define them inside a subscribe. Use a higher observable instead.

```js
    ...
    this.fights$ = auth.user$.pipe(
        tap(user => console.log('is user emitting?: ', user)),
        take(1),
        mergeMap(user => {
            this.userId = user.uid
            this.fightCollection = this.afs.collection<any>(`users/${this.userId}/Fights`);
            return this.fightCollection.valueChanges();
        }),
        tap(fights => console.log('fights value: ', fights))
    );
    ...
```

Adding `tap` operator helps you to know if your observables are actually emitting something.

Also, I think there's a typo in your html, it should be fights$:

```html
<ul *ngFor="let fight of fights$ | async">
 <li>
  {{fight.blueFighter}}
 </li>
</ul>
```